# How to update the CSS of an iFrame with pure javascript not with jquery

Tags: javascript, css

I want to apply the custom CSS for the below iframe,

```
<iframe width="100%" class="freshwidget-embedded-form" id="freshwidget-embedded-form" src="http://customerservice.millers.com.au/widgets/feedback_widget/new?&amp;widgetType=embedded&amp;screenshot=no" scrolling="no" height="550px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Please let me know how will i be able to modify the CSS of any class/element within the iFrame via JavaScript.

Comment: if it's a different domain, there is no way

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you please help me understand to check if 2 sites are in same domain or not.

Comment: Protocol host and port must be identical

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this. iFrame is hosted within the hostname, http://millers.com.au, but the iFrame is pointing to http://customerservice.millers.com.au

So u meant to say, ill not be able to update the CSS for the elements within the iFrame in this scenario?

Comment: Subdomains can be tricky

Comment: By that I mean, yes there is a way, but I'm not really conversant with how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not clear enough but I am going ahead and assume that you want to change the style or an attribute such as "src" using pure javascript,

So to change a style you have to grab the id or class then change the style, in your case it will be.

```
document.getElementById(freshwidget-embedded-form).style.width = "new_width"
```

or if you want to change the source it will be like

```
document.getElementById(freshwidget-embedded-form).src = "new src for the media"
```

Comment: I wanted to update the CSS of one the class/element with in an iFrame via JavaScript

Comment: you can not update style or script within iframe , you have to change it first in source of iframe than embed , you can not change css etc of any element inside iframe